# My japan landing permission date is higher than my japan tourist visa, which date should i follow for departure?

Tags: visas, japan

I just arrived a couple of days to Japan and my single entry visa expires in 6 days, I had my departure flight on the last day of the visa. But when  I pass the border security gate the sticker of landing permission says that the permit date is until the last day of May.

which should I follow: keep my flight to the last day of the visa or can I stay some extra days because the landing permission sticker says so?

Comment: You used your **entry visa** to enter and recieved a **permit to stay** until the last day of May. What is not clear?

Comment: Got confused since i thought the entry visa expiry date was the one to follow while staying here

Comment: @MarkJohnson Not clear perhaps due to the fact thar many visas (such as Schengen) work differently.